# Can I disable the Dashboard window when SpringSource Tool Suite starts up?

Tags: ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

There apparently used to be a toggle switch on the Dashboard itself, but that's gone, and I can't find anything in the Preferences.  I'm using version 2.5.2.

I know it's really not a big deal, but closing that window over and over is starting to make Jack a dull boy, if you catch my drift.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

From the menu select Window / Preferences.  Look under Spring / Dashboard.  Uncheck 'Show Dashboard on Startup'

(On newer versions of the spring plugin, it is under SpringSource / Dashboard)

Comment: Classic.  Not only is it painfully easy to do, but the answer comes from somebody I almost emailed (en masse) to ask the same stupid question.  Hi Brent.  My last name is Jones.  You can't escape.  +1 For being you.

Comment: In juno, this appears to have moved to SpringSource->Dashboard.  And...  _It doesnt seem to work..._  I unchecked the checkbox and still get the dashboard on every startup.  Furthermore, it seems to add one with each startup.  So, if i didnt close the last one, the next time i start up i have 2.  Any ideas here?

Comment: @Lucas Fortunatelly, it works for Kepler. It's very annoying.

Comment: Helped me a lot ! Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately, this option does not appear to exist any more.  The only options on the preferences page now are "Use Old Dashboard" and "News Feed Updates".

Answer (score 4):

go to Windows---->Preference---->SpringSource---->DashBoard
uncheck [] Show Dashboard on Startup
click on OK button.

Answer (score 3):

STS 3.7.1 (Eclipse Mars) has no options to disable dashboard on startup.

However, if you go to Windows->Preferences->Spring->Dashboard and then check box "Use Old Dashboard", next time you start STS, dashboard page will not open. Go figure.

Comment: Still true in STS 3.8.1.  Checking this makes the old version of the dashboard appear when chosen from Help/Dashboard, but it does not appear at startup.  Whether this is intentional or a bug that hasn't been fixed yet, I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MAC, using spring tool suit latest version 3.4.0.RELEASE. By clicking the menu Spring Tool Suite / Preferences, then SpringSource / Dashboard, uncheck Show Dashboard On Startup  works for me.